# Motherboard and power supply compatibility

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, atx

I just bought a Gigabyte GA-P55A-UD3 mother board and an Antec BP550 Plus power supply.  When I was connecting the ATX 12V connector from the power supply (which is two 2x2 connectors) I noticed that the connector on the mother board is keyed in such a way that only one of the 2x2 connectors plugs in.

Is there some sort of adapter I need to get to make this work?  Would it be disastrous to only connect one of the 2x2 connectors?  Do I just need a new power supply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I called tech support and they told me that as long as the CPU runs at 95w or lower it is perfectly OK to only use the 2x2 connector and leave the other part empty.  Since i'm running an I5 Lynfield 670 i should be fine.  Hope this helps someone.

P.S. They have great tech support.  Nice to talk with someone in tech support that actually knows what they are talking about...

Comment: This is correct.  A lot of low-power power supplies ONLY have the four pins instead of 8.  (You also sometimes see boards with a removable cap over 4 of the pins for this reason.)

Answer (score 0):

The 8-pin ATX 12V from the power supply *should* connect just fine to the motherboard. The [power supply manual](http://www.antec.com/pdf/manuals/BP550_plus_EN_manual.pdf) shows that there's also a 6+2 pin PCI-E power cable. Is it possible that you're trying the PCI-E power cable instead of the ATX12V?

Comment: No it is definitely the atx12v.

Comment: Since you describe them as two 2x2 connectors you are probably expected to slide the two together to form a single 4x2 before you plug it (them) in.

Comment: From the OP: "the connector on the mother board is keyed in such a way that only one of the 2x2 connectors plugs in. "